# QGIS 3 Metadata to ISO XML

Tags: qgis, metadata, iso-19115

Just found out that QGis 3.x has a metadata editor. That is great! Is there a tool to convert the metadata saved by QGIS (*.qmd* file) to a ISO-xml standard metadata file?

Why am I asking this: I though of using QGis to create the xml metadata file that we will use to populate a Metadata Catalog

Comment: I agree that as the metadata gathered appears to conform to the INSPIRE profile ISO 19139 it would be helpful to be able to export in that schema.   Can't work out if it is already in hand though ~ https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/91

Comment: I read a .qmd file using vi and it is XML. I suspect an easy translation to ISO metadata can be done using xslt. But a previous analysis beween GIS and ISO Metadata schemas have to be done in order to correctly perform such task.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on this but I think metadata is a work in progress, being approached from a number of angles.

If you have metadata to save, apparently it can be saved to a file which sits in the same directory as the data. As per this answer QGIS Default Metadata

If you are trying to read existing metadata from another system (your case) I presume QGIS is expecting to read a *.qmd file.

There is a plugin which apparently used to help some users, but apparently it no longer works with updated version of QGIS. https://github.com/nextgis/metatools/issues

Comment: Where does the ISO element of this question fit within your answer?